# C++ private constant pointer

Tags: c++

I am learning pointers in c++ and am having some trouble.
I have a class `Foo` that in the header file declares some data:

```
private:
const Bar *obj;
```

Where `Bar` is a class.

Then in the c++ implementation I want to replace `*obj` so that it points to a completely different `Bar` object. `*obj` is constant, so how do I change what is in what `*obj` points to or rather, what is in memory at `*obj`? Also in `Foo`'s destructor, how do I deallocate `*obj`?

Comment: You want to _replace `*obj` so that it points to a completely different `Bar` object._ I am not sure I understand what that means. Do you want to have `obj` point to a different `Bar` object (no problem doing that), or do you what to change the contents of the object to which `obj` currently points (that isn't possible due to the `const`)?

Comment: Yes, I want `obj` to point to a new `Bar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your class definition

```
class A {
private:
  const Bar *obj;
};
```

`obj` is a pointer to a constant `Bar` object. You can change what that pointer points to, but you cannot change the contents of the object pointed to.

So, if you have a new `Bar` object and you'd like to change `obj` so it points to that, you can simply assign the new value:

```
/* New object: */
Bar *new_bar = new Bar;
/* Change the pointer: */
obj = new_bar;
```

There are two issues, however.

1. If the new `Bar` object is created **outside the class**, you cannot directly assign it to `obj` because the latter is **private**. Hence you need a setter function:

   ```
   class A {
   private:
     const Bar *obj;
   public:
     void set_obj(const Bar *new_obj) { obj = new_obj; }
   };
   ```
2. **You must determine who will eventually own the `Bar` object**, i.e. who is responsible for freeing the heap space it takes. If the caller is responsible then you can code it as above, i.e. `class A` will never create new `Bar` objects, nor delete any. It will just maintain a pointer to `Bar` objects created and deleted outside the class.

   But if `class A` above is actually responsible for the memory space taken by the `Bar` objects, you must use `delete obj` in the destructor to free the space, and you must also free the space when you get a new `Bar` object assigned. That is, the `set_obj` function above needs to be changed to this:

   ```
   void set_obj(const Bar *new_obj) { delete obj; obj = new_obj; }
   ```

   Otherwise you'll have a memory leak. Similar measures must be taken in the copy constructor (unless you delete it), as well as the assignment operator: Both functions are used whenever a *copy* of a `class A` object is made, and in that case you must make sure that you do *not simply copy* the pointer, but instead allocate fresh space and copy the object (i.e. you must perform a deep copy):

   ```
   A(const A& a):obj(new Bar(*a.obj)) {}
   A& operator=(const A& a) { delete obj; obj = new Bar(*a.obj); return *this; }
   ```

   Having said this, if your class is responsible for the memory space, it is a *much better* idea to use a smart pointer class instead of a raw pointer. The main reasons are: (i) The above is quite complicated and it's easy to make mistakes; (ii) The above is still not very good – there may still be memory leaks or worse problems when an exception is thrown, e.g. in the constructor of `Bar`. C++11 provides a smart pointer class called `std::unique_ptr`, which seems ideal for your purposes:

   ```
   class A {
   private:
     std::unique_ptr<const Bar> obj;
   public:
     ~A() {}
     void set_obj(std::unique_ptr<const Bar> new_obj) { obj = new_obj; }
   };
   ```

   With this in place, the smart pointer will take care of any memory space that needs to be freed automatically, both at destruction time as well as when a new `Bar` object is assigned to the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use that pointer to to change the value that's being pointed to, that's why it's a const, but you should be able to change what it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

On c++ "const Bar *obj;" means that you have a pointer to a readonly Bar object; meaning that you can point it to any readonly Bar object.

You can also point a non constant variable, thus promising that you will not change it using that pointer.

If you want to have a pointer, that is constant in the sense that it can't be made to point anything else, then you should write it this way:

```
Bar * const obj = some_object;
```

This will compile and work fine:

```
const int p = 1, q = 2;
int r = 3;
const int* i = &p;
i = &q; // point it to a different const variable.
i = &r; // point it to a different non const variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

As written I believe that this is a pointer to a const Bar object and not a constant pointer.